# How to read json file into java with jackson library?

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, convertfrom-json

I want to read this simple JSONfile with java jackson library(I'm new to JSON).

Coud you please tell to me what i do wrong?I created class or JSON object wrongly or this metod of convertion JSON object to Java is wrong, thanks

> Edit now i get set of exception like this

[image]

This is what the JSONfile stores

```
 {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Steve",
      "Datax": {
        "veek": "vect",
        "seev": "vecs"
      }
    }
```

And i have three classes

Here is a Cevan:

```
public class Cevan {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Datax data;

    public Datax getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Datax data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

and Datax:

```
public class Datax {
    private String veek;
    private String seev;

    public String getSeev() {
        return seev;
    }

    public String getVeek() {
        return veek;
    }

    public void setSeev(String seev) {
        this.seev = seev;
    }

    public void setVeek(String veek) {
        this.veek = veek;
    }
}
```

and Class Main:

```
     public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is= Cevan.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json2.json");
        Cevan testObj = mapper.readValue(is, Cevan.class);


    }
}
```

It's like my project looks

[image]

Comment: Check that the json file exists in the path and the InputStream is not null.

Comment: I checked InputStream with if statement and it's null,but the JSON file consists properties and exists

Comment: Then the problem is with the path, loading resources in Java can be tricky because of the classpath, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be nice to have the log files attached as text and not as image.

The problem should be in the json file.

According to your java classes the json file should be as follows:

```
 {
  "id": 15,
  "name": "Steve",
  "data": {
    "veek": "vect",
    "seev": "vecs"
  }
}
```

Note the object attribute change from "Datax" to "data".

Answer (score 1):

Change your `resourseStreamReader` from

```
InputStream is=Cevan.class.getResourceAsStream("json2.json");
```

to:

```
InputStream is = this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json2.json");
```

and also make sure what your `json2.json` is in `classpath`

Comment: JSON file is in classpath, but for sure i tried to use absolute path but i get same error

Comment: try to use InputStream is = this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("json2.json");

Comment: change from "Datax" to  "data" in json property name in json and java class must be same